# Polynomials and Divisibility Rule.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, divisibility

The question is this -

> If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are two polynomials such that the polynomial $h(x)=xf(x^3)+x^2g(x^6)$ is divisible by $x^2+x+1$, then which of the following are true?
>   
>  1. $f(1)=g(1)$
>   
>  2. $f(1)=-g(1)$
>   
>  3. $h(1)=0$

So I wrote out this $$xf(x^3)+x^2g(x^6)=Q(x).(x^2+x+1)$$
where $Q(x)$ is the quotient polynomial.

Then I tried substituting a few values like $1$ and $0$, but these get me nowhere. The $Q(x)$ is making problems and also the fact that $x^2+x+1=0$ does not have easy to substitute roots.

Can anyone give any hints or general tips regarding questions like these? Thank you.

**Edit** Real coefficients to the polynomials might have to be assumed, I'm not sure.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti One or more options might be correct.

Comment: to reduce the RHS put $x^2=-x-1$ because $x^2+x+1=0$ 
note that ax+b=0   
so $$x^3=x(x^2)=x(-x-1)=\\-x^2-x=\\-(-x-1)-x=+1\\so \\x^6=(x^3)^2=1^2=1\\xf(x^3)+x^2g(x^6)=q(x)(0)+0\\xf(x^3)+x^2g(x^6)=0\\xf(1)+(-x-1)g(1)=0\\x(f(1)-g(1))-g(1)=0$$

Comment: @daryakhosrotash Thank you for answering, please post it as an answer :)

Comment: Why is $x^2+x+1=0$?

Comment: to find remainder  ,we put $x^2+x+1=0$

Comment: @daryakhosrotash When you substitute $x^2+x+1=0$ why is $ax+b=0$?

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Nothing is specified as such.

Comment: ax+b=0 , as question said , $h(x)$ is  divisible $x^2+x+1$

Comment: @daryakhosrotash Right, How did I forget that?! Edited the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\omega=-\frac12+\frac i2\sqrt 3$ be a root of $x^2+x+1$. Then  $\omega^3=1$ and $\omega^2=\overline \omega$ is the other root.  Therefore,
$$\omega f(1)+\overline\omega g(1) =Q(\omega)\cdot 0 $$
and also
$$\overline \omega f(1)+\omega g(1) =Q(\omega^2)\cdot 0 $$
from which we conclude $f(1)=g(1)=0$, so that all three claims are correct.